# How can access to start up menu on Macbook Air 2011?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I have a Macbook air 2011 /4g/ 11" , I format my hdd from disk utility and now I want to access to startup menu to reinstall it, I try that with holding option key and it just show me the internet recovery, my  internet speed is very low, after about 8 hours it's show me the start up menu finally and ask me to reinstall the lion 1.7 so on that time because of some issues I just turn my macbook off because I think everything downloaded,

Now, again when i turn it on for continue the installing process it's show me again the internet recovery and want to download from internet again

How can I access to the downloaded data and continue the installation (command+r and option key again get me directly to Internet Recovery)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start using Internet Recovery, and once it's started (which can take a while) you can then select the menu item to install the OS. See the (rather detailed) description of the Internet Recovery system [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718).

Please note that with a slow internet connection, this is going to be a slow process. This is because after downloading and running the Recovery system, it is then going to go away and download the OS installer - and that is quite large.

An alternative might be to go to an Apple Store and borrow their (rather fast!) WiFi connection to do this, if you have one close by.

Comment: This for sure, but I'd like to add that if you do have access to an Apple store the Genius Bar would be happy to install the operating system for you, which will take even less time than the internet recovery option on a fast internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the USB recovery key that comes with the Macbook Air.  If you don't have the one that came with this computer, that's another thing you could ask for at an Apple Store (or from someone else who has an Air).